# A battle of thousand units

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity3d, how can i implement a battle of 200 prefabs versus another 200 prefabs?

Let say i have a support prefabs that increase armor of friendly prefabs and decrease armor of hostile prefabs at the same time. In a huge battle where 400 prefabs (friendly and hostile) are close to each other it would result in enormous amount of calculation and drastically reduce the fps down to 2 or 3.

I googled it and found something interesting called culling scheme. But I can't understand it or figure out how to implement it in unity.

Here is the link: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/overlapsphere-with-hundreds-of-agents-and-performance.157690/

So,
1. Could you please explain to me how to use the culling scheme method in the link above?
2. Is there any other approach in implementing a battle where there are hundred of prefabs at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information doesn't seem to be reliable. However what was described as *Culling Scheme* is actually a simple idea but how to implement it is highly dependent on your game.

The idea is to separate units based on their location, so that interactive operations (Attacks, Defense, AI, etc...) work on only those that are close enough to each other.

There are 2 different methods that I can think of:

1. Divide the map into rows and columns, calculate interactions within each 2x2 square. A,B,C fit in the same square. Also B,C,D. But not A,D.

[image: A,B,C fit in the same square. Also B,C,D]

2. Use colliders with triggers and add/remove each unit to a collection when it enters/exits the collider. So that you can easily do the interactive operations within each collection.

My guess is if you choose the first option it will be easy to implement but since you should update the square members more often than the second option, it has some performance issues.

If you choose the second one (it needs more research on how to use triggers, kinematic, rigid body...) and do it right, you will less likely encounter performance issues.

---

### edit

In each 2x2 square these 5 are the only necessary interactions to be processed **IF** the previous squares are already processed:

```
   (first 1x1 square, last 1x1 square) 
   (second 1x1 square, last 1x1 square) 
   (third 1x1 square, last 1x1 square) 
   (within last 1x1 square) 
   (second 1x1 square, third 1x1 square)
```

Suppose we have an area divided into 3 rows and 3 columns. We add an extra row and column to simplify the calculations (the zero squares are outside boundary and thus no units will be in them)

[image]

Now in each 2x2 square (e.g 1,2,4,5) there are 10 types of interactions:

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,4) (1,5)
      (2,2) (2,4) (2,5)
            (4,4) (4,5)
                  (5,5)
```

If we process these interactions sequentially like below, We can make sure no interaction is made twice.

[image]

e.g.

1. in step1 (1,1) is seen.
2. in step2 (2,2) and (1,2) are seen.
3. in step4 (4,4) and (1,4) are seen.

So what's left for step 5 is:

```
(1,5) (2,5) (4,5) (5,5) (2,4)
```

Obviously it goes the same for the 2x2 squares which contain zero squares. only that we skip the interactions involving a 0.

Comment: But what if: let say point B were a blue point and it need to interact with point C? Since interaction only done in each green square and B and C are in different squares they cannot see each other as far as i understand.

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear. let's say every 2x2 square. which means each unit exist in 4 different 2x2 squares.

Comment: Wow, am i missing something or i have to calculate the interaction between  A and B twice. Since they are in the same two 2x2 squares?

Comment: That is a precise observation however there are workarounds for that. Please see the edit answer.

Comment: Currently i am working on the PAC architecture problem while seeking outside help on performance issues. But it seems to be more complicated than i expected. It was very kind of you to have explained to me in very detail. I will sure look into your answer later on and see how i can apply it into my project. I have one year experience with Unity so basics concepts like triggers, kinematic, rigid body are very familiar to me. Thank you very much for your help. If only i could give you 5/5 stars. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Thank you :)